# Tensorflow Error: Cannot assign a device for operation 'Tile'

Tags: tensorflow

tf.tile operation fails to execute on GPU device.
This code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    tt = tf.tile(tf.range(4), [3])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tt))
```

Results in:

```
Caused by op u'Tile', defined at:
  File "test_tf3.py", line 6, in <module>
    tt = tf.tile(tf.range(4), [3])
  File "/media/awork/home/astepochkin/drecs/repo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3847, in tile
    name=name)
  File "/media/awork/home/astepochkin/drecs/repo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/media/awork/home/astepochkin/drecs/repo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/media/awork/home/astepochkin/drecs/repo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation 'Tile': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
     [[Node: Tile = Tile[T=DT_INT32, Tmultiples=DT_INT32, _device="/device:GPU:0"](range, Tile/multiples)]]
```

I have looked into tensorflow sources and found files implementing tile for GPU. So I do not understand why it does not work.
Could anyone please help me?

Comment: As a workaround you could cast it to float and then back to int just before indexing. Also if this slows things down a lot in a practical use-case, it makes sense to file a feature request in tensorflow github

Comment: Somebody just added int32 GPU support for tile, it'll probably get merged to master today -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/12183

Comment: Yeah ... because I've asked for it :) I asked for all integer types but they added only for int32, It is better than nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your type is int32 and no GPU kernel is registered for this type.

Comment: It seems to me that it is a strange limitation. I need some indexing arithmetic and I do not want to move quite a large index tensors between CPU and GPU memories. What is the reason for such a limitation?

Comment: it looks like gather uses different macro to register its index tensor, so it can still be on GPU (the "axis" parameter is still stored on CPU due to HostMemory annotation) -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d0750e970ff448177e759f9cc4c34d60b787cd21/tensorflow/core/kernels/gather_op.cc#L121